# Simplifying log likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

I'm currently studying for my machine learning exam, and have come across a slide regarding optimizing using maximum likelihood. I get the ideas  behind what optimization is used for, but I can't figure out how log(y_1, x_1,...,y_n, x_n|w) was simplified (second line).

Is it just an assumption of independence? I would be grateful if anybody can clarify.

Note that in this example x_i is the training data, and y_i is the value assosciated to that data (can be a class or a real-value if it was a regression problem)

[image]

Comment: Yes, when you sample it is assumed that each observation in the sample is independently drawn from the population.

Comment: Chain rule? We use that $P(A \mbox{ and } B)=P(A)\cdot P(B)$ when $A, B$ are independent events.

Comment: A little confused here. Where does the condition go? I thought we'd use the chain rule and then assume independence to simplify it#

Comment: What is the chain rule?

Comment: Nevermind, I'm being stupid. Confusing myself because we're still assuming x_i and y_i are not independent. It's essentially like P(A,B|C) = P(A|C)*P(B|C) right?

Comment: The chain rule is here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_rule_%28probability%29 (it would take me a year to type out...). But we have a condition so it's not actually applicable.

Comment: Yes, sorry. You draw samples as pairs $(x_i,y_i)$. So $(x_1,y_1)$ is independent of $(x_2,y_2)$ but $y_1$ is not independent of $x_1$. My fault.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, appreciated :)

Comment: Ok, link was ok, no need to type it! No, actually what you wrote in your comment is what we use. The chain rule is something a little bit different.

Comment: Okay, thanks again :)